# show menu when paused a game ins spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I created a game like as tower defence. I can successfully "pause" all game. And then i can resume the game with these code:

```
let startLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y);
let myNodeName = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
if(myNodeName.Name == "Start"){
   self.view!.paused = false
}
if(myNodeName.Name == "pause"){
   self.view!.paused = true 
   self.showPausedMenu()
}
```

In showPausedMenu function. I design a menu with SKLabelNodes and SKSpriteNodes. However when i paused the game all of these "node creation" things also paused. So nothing happen. How i can show my menu while game is paused?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solve my problem. While paused the game, all screen freezed however gamescene still detect all "touch" and if it has node name then we can do some operations. At this point, the proble is only showing my menu. So here is my solution.before I paused game, i added my menu on the screen. then pause the game.
In live version is

```
let startLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y);
let myNodeName = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
if(myNodeName.Name == "Start"){
   self.view!.paused = false
   self.removePausedMenu()
}
if(myNodeName.Name == "pause"){
   self.showPausedMenu()
}
```

showPausedMenu is:

```
func showPausedMenu(){
    .....
    .....
    /* Create menu and buttons and labels with NODES. and add to parent as child nodes. */
    self.view!.paused = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're pausing the view itself. Pausing the view stops all of the logic.

If you need to do a pause menu, you need to either add a subview that will appear on top of your view to manage all of the interactions with the user, or you need to not pause the view, but put the view ELEMENTS on pause and create things on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to make use of a `SKNode` group which consist of all the objects that you want to be paused.

In this way, you retain full control of the elements that you want to pause or unpause